# Classical vs GLM aproaches for calculating two-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model

1. What is the main difference between the classical approach of the
   calculation of two-way ANOVA and the general linear model (GLM) approach?
2. Is it possible to determine the coefficients of a general linear
   model from the output of the classical two-way ANOVA?

The classical approach is based on the Fisher's method.